# Storing and indexing datetime2 vs bit + datetime2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have somewhat large table (~20 million rows) and need to store `bit` information with additional `datetime2`. I know I will always query only on the `bit` information and when `bit` information is 1, there is always `datetime2` information present. I'm considering two ways of implementing this:

a) indexes would contain only `Enabled`

```
create table Items ( 
    Enabled bit not null,
    EnabledWhen datetime2 null
)
```

b) indexes would contain only `Enabled`, but query will always be either `Enabled is null` or `Enabled is not null`

```
create table Items (
    Enabled datetime2 null
)
```

Which version is more efficient and why?

Comment: As Eric Lippert would say, [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: And then as I would say, don't *store* data that can be computed, unless or until you've demonstrated an actual performance issue. If `Enabled` always logically follows the `null`/`not null` nature of another column, just use that until you've demonstrated a problem. Then consider whether you can have the *system* maintain this computed data rather than having to do it yourself (e.g. a persisted computed column, maybe?), so that *you* don't have to make sure that your data is *consistent*.

Comment: `bit` makes a very poor choice for an index, because of low selectivity. It is almost guaranteed that such an index won't be considered in majority of scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without your use case.  Indexing a bit column will be just a bit more efficient than a date column because the index can be smaller and fit more records in a page, however, adding the bit column will make your table a little bit wider, i.e. slightly less efficient.

If you're using a clustered index, do not add the bit column and just index the date.

If this is a covering non-clustered index and you need the date column included, don't add the bit column, index the date instead.

If this is for a covering non-clustered index that does not need the date, use the bit column and include your needed columns assuming the date is not included and you're not going to create another non-clustered index with the date column.

In general, I feel like the bit column is a waste of space as the use case is very narrow.